# Ionic + Angular unable to ion-radio to be checked by default

Tags: javascript, angularjs, radio-button

I'm trying to check one from radio buttons in radio list, but without luck.

Could somebody tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

**I tried to do it by this way:**

```
<div class="list">

      <ion-radio ng-repeat="item in goalTypeList"
                 ng-value="item.value"
                 ng-change="goalTypeChanged(item)"
                 ng-checked="item.selected"
                 ng-model="data.clientSide">
          {{ item.text }}
      </ion-radio>

  </div>
```

**JS:**

```
.controller('SettingsCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading) {

        $scope.goalTypeList = [
            { text: "Dials", value: "dials", selected: true },
            { text: "Conversations", value: "conversations" , selected: false  },
            { text: "Appointments", value: "appointments" , selected: false },
            { text: "Orders", value: "orders", selected: false  }
        ];

        $scope.data = {
            clientSide: 'ng'
        };

        $scope.goalTypeChanged = function(item) {
            console.log("Selected goalType, text:", item.text, "value:", item.value);
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the value of data.clientSide is not in the list goalTypeList. Change the value to match any..

html:

```html
<div class="list">

  <ion-radio ng-repeat="item in goalTypeList"
             ng-value="item.value"
             ng-change="goalTypeChanged(item)"
             ng-checked="item.selected"
             ng-model="data.clientSide">
      {{ item.text }}
  </ion-radio>
```

js:

```js
  .controller('SettingsCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading) {

    $scope.goalTypeList = [
        { text: "Dials", value: "dials", selected: true },
        { text: "Conversations", value: "conversations" , selected: false  },
        { text: "Appointments", value: "appointments" , selected: false },
        { text: "Orders", value: "orders", selected: false  }
    ];

    $scope.data = {
        clientSide: 'appointments'
    };

    $scope.goalTypeChanged = function(item) {
        console.log("Selected goalType, text:", item.text, "value:", item.value);
    };
```

Comment: Please use English for answers it makes it a lot easier to understand.

Comment: It feels exclusive, but StackOverflow is an English-only site. Please only respond in English, even if your English is not that great. People can always edit your answer to improve anything that might be unclear. If you're interested in a Spanish StackOverflow, there is a proposal for that here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish

Answer (score 1):

The value in your `$scope.data = { clientSide: 'ng' };` doesn't match any of the values in `$scope.goalTypeList`.

If the clientSide value on `$scope.data` was either dials, conversations, appointments or orders then the radio buttons should then load with one of the radio buttons selected.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know what to pass into $scope.data ?

Comment: Set the clientSide value in $scope.data to be whatever you want to be the default value selected on the radio buttons. If you want nothing selected by default set clientSide = ''

Answer (score 0):

Like @Marc Harry said your `ng-value` should be equal `ng-model`. To make it more dynamic *(let's say you get an object from the backend and the selected value may change)* you could do following:

```
<div class="list">

      <ion-radio ng-repeat="item in goalTypeList"
                 ng-value="item.value"
                 ng-checked="item.selected"
                 ng-model="data.clientSide">
          {{ item.text }}
      </ion-radio>

</div>
```

---

```
.controller('SettingsCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading) {

    $scope.goalTypeList = [
        { text: "Dials", value: "dials", selected: true },
        { text: "Conversations", value: "conversations" , selected: false  },
        { text: "Appointments", value: "appointments" , selected: false },
        { text: "Orders", value: "orders", selected: false  }
    ];

    $scope.data = {
        clientSide: selectedValue()
    };

    function selectedValue = function() {
        for(let i = 0; i < $scope.goalTypeList.length; i++) {
            if ($scope.goalTypeList[i].selected) {
                return $scope.goalTypeList[i].value;
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ion-select also with ionChange event:

```
 <ion-select (ionChange)="checkValue($event)"  interface="popover" 
  placeholder="Select One" >
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let item of userData" [value]="item"> 
   {{item.optionA}}</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

In your typeScript:

```
checkValue(event){ console.log(event.detail.value)}
```