# default value radio button into ng-repeat angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

as the title i need to select the first radio button as a default value into the ng-repeat.

```
  <div class="customRadio" ng-repeat="item in fundSwitch.compatibleFund track by $index">

   <ion-radio name="rifFondo" ng-model="dispositive.request.rifFondo" ng-value="item.codiceIsin" ng-checked="$first">
     <h3>{{item.descrizioneFondo}} {{$index}}</h3>
     <p><strong>Data valorizzazione :</strong> {{item.dataQuotazione}}</p>
   </ion-radio>
 </div>
```

i tried other condition into ng-checked :  ng-checked="$index == 0", but it didn' work.

Comment: I don't think ng-checked and ng-model should be used together.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked

How about initializing the value of item.codiceIsin to the first element in the array?

Comment: I can't because the value of item.codiceIsin is assigned dynamically from response of server.

Comment: sorry, meant the value of rifFondo - not sure if that matters to your answer.

Comment: i need to iterate the array before it's binding in the view, are there another way ?

Comment: @stephen.vakil i assigned the first value of array it worked for me ;) thanks

Comment: may be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/q/26039271/4302328

Answer (score 0):

i solved it assigning the first value of array as suggested me :

```
$scope.fundSwitch.compatibleFund = FundService.extractFundSwitchParams(data)['fondiCompatibili'];
    $scope.dispositive.request.rifFondo = $scope.fundSwitch.compatibleFund[0].codiceIsin;
```

thanks for the help.